# NSQueueOperation weird behavior

Tags: ios

I am adding multiple instances of subclass of NSOperation in a for loop:

```
NSMutableArray * operations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
     for(int i =1; i<81;i++){
         [operations addObject:[[PDFGenerator alloc]initWithPageNumber:i andPDFParser:pdf]];
     }
    [_queue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished: NO];
```

in PDFGenerator I have a variable that stores the current page number for the operation.

```
@implementation PDFGenerator
int pageCounter;
```

In the main method of the PDFGenerator I am logging the current page number and it prints 
80 for ALL the operations!

I already fixed by using @property for the current page count, 
but I am trying to understand why it's happening. Any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just use:

```
int pageCounter;
```

You are creating a global variable. Presuming you set this at each iteration, then refer to it in your PDFGenerator methods, it will always use the last value it was set to.

Example:

```
// Bar.h
@interface Bar : NSObject
FOUNDATION_EXPORT int someThing;
@end

// Bar.m
@implementation Bar
int someThing;
@end

// Foo.m
#import "Foo.h"
#import "Bar.h"

@implementation Foo
- (void)doSomething 
{
    ++someThing;
}
@end
```

That's totally valid code, and calls to `[Foo doSomething]` increment `someThing`.

If you wanted an instance variable, it would look like this:

```
@interface Bar()
{
    int someThing;
}

@end

@implementation Bar
- (void)doSomething
{
    ++someThing;
}
@end
```

In this case `someThing` is defined as an instance variable (not a global variable). It is an accessible part of objects of the `Bar`.

Comment: Hmm, It still doesn't make sense to me. int pageCounter; is global but in the context of the PDFGenerator class, correct? 

[[PDFGenerator alloc]initWithPageNumber:i andPDFParser:pdf]] is creating a new instance of PDFGenerator that is initialized with different i each time...

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski Nope, it's application global (you could add `extern int pageCounter` in your header and access it from anywhere). You may have been trying to create an instance variable, which is done between { } in the interface.

Comment: I didn't realize it.
Thanks!